# How to store info from an Array to an Array Object?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, arrayobject

I have a Java class which uses BufferedReader to obtain information from a text file, then store the information into an Array called `newData` . I want to store a certain part of the information to the `VegTypes[f] = new VegType();` but I not sure what code should I write here to obtain that part of information.

Without completing this part, I am not able to continue working on another Array Object which is `Vegs[i] = new Veg(newData[0], newData[1], newData[2],);` for storing information together with VegTypes Array Object.

**Below is my code of the Java class:**

```
public class theVegetable {

    private Veg[] Vegs;
    private VegType[] VegTypes;

    public theVegetable() {
        int quantity;
        int vegQuantity;
        String vegLine;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("vegetableInfo.txt"));
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(vegLine.readLine());

            Vegs = new Veg[quantity];

            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
               vegLine = br.readLine();
                String[] newData = vegLine.split(";");

                vegQuantity = Integer.parseInt(newData[3]);


                //For loop to store information into VegTypes
                for (int f = 0; j < vegQuantity; f++) {
                    
                    VegTypes[f] = new VegType();
                    
                }
                
                //Vegs Array Object to store information plus VegTypes
                Vegs[i] = new Veg(newData[0], newData[1], newData[2],);

            }

            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is my vegetableInfo.txt text file:**

```
3
Tomato;class1;Malaysia Tomato;2;MT100A;MT1;200;90;MT20A;MT2;600;80;Malaysia product
Avocado;class2;Europe Avocado;4;EA100A;EA1;300;90;EA14A;EA2;90;80;EA230A;EA3;43;50.9;EA470A;EA4;400;76;Europe product
Cabbage;class3;Malaysia Cabbage;3;MC100A;MC1;500;20;MC49A;MC2;500;50;MC800A;MC3;600;10.3;Malaysia product
```

The number 3 at the top of the text file is for the `int quantity;` variable to store the amount.
The kind of information I want the `VegTypes[f] = new VegType();` to store are `MT100A;MT1;200;90;MT20A;MT2;600;80;`, the number 2 besides the Malaysia Tomato are for `int vegQuantity;` variable. Same thing goes for other vegetables in the text file.

**Constructor of my** `private VegType[] VegTypes;` **Array Object:**

```
private String vegCode;
private String vegBatch;
private int vegBatchQuantity;
private double vegGrade;

    public VegType(String inVegCode, String inVegBatch, int inVegBatchQuantity, double inVegGrade) {
        vegCode = inVegCode;
        vegBatch = inVegBatch;
        vegBatchQuantity = inVegBatchQuantity;
        vegGrade = inVegGrade;
    }
```

**My Veg Class:**

```
public class Veg {

    private String vegetableName;
    private String classLevel;
    private String productionCountry;
    private VegType[] VegTypes;
    private String productType;

    //Constructor
    public Veg(String inVegetableName, String inClassLevel, String inProductionCountry, VegType[] inVegTypes, String inProductType) {
        vegetableName = inVegetableName;
        classLevel = inClassLevel;
        productionCountry = inProductionCountry;
        vegType = inVegTypes;
        
        productType = inProductType;
    }


    public String getVegetableName() {
        return vegetableName;
    }

    public String getClassLevel() {
        return classLevel;
    }

    public String getProductionCountry() {
        return productionCountry;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always try to provide the sufficient information in-order others to provide clean and complete answer. Here you have not provided `class Veg` and still you're having problem with passing **VegType** array to **Veg** constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
class VegType {
    private String vegCode;
    private String vegBatch;
    private int vegBatchQuantity;
    private double vegGrade;

    public VegType(String inVegCode, String inVegBatch, int inVegBatchQuantity, double inVegGrade) {
        vegCode = inVegCode;
        vegBatch = inVegBatch;
        vegBatchQuantity = inVegBatchQuantity;
        vegGrade = inVegGrade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return vegCode+" "+vegBatch+" "+vegBatchQuantity+" "+vegGrade;
    }
}

class Veg {
    private String vegetableName;
    private String classLevel;
    private String productionCountry;
    private VegType[] VegTypes;
    private String productType;

    //Constructor
    public Veg(String inVegetableName, String inClassLevel, String inProductionCountry, VegType[] inVegTypes, String inProductType) {
        vegetableName = inVegetableName;
        classLevel = inClassLevel;
        productionCountry = inProductionCountry;
        VegTypes = inVegTypes;
        productType = inProductType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return vegetableName+" "+classLevel+" "+productionCountry+" "+VegTypes+" "+productType;
    }

    public String getVegetableName() {
        return vegetableName;
    }

    public String getClassLevel() {
        return classLevel;
    }

    public String getProductionCountry() {
        return productionCountry;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }
}


class TheVegetable {
    private Veg[] Vegs;
    private VegType[] VegTypes;

    public TheVegetable() throws IOException {
        int quantity;
        int vegQuantity;
        String vegLine;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("vegetableInfo.txt"));
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            Vegs = new Veg[quantity];

            for (int i=0; i<quantity; i++) {
                vegLine = br.readLine();
                String[] newData = vegLine.split(";");

                vegQuantity = Integer.parseInt(newData[3]);
                VegTypes=new VegType[vegQuantity];
                for(int j=4, k=0; j<newData.length-1; j+=4, k++) {
                    VegTypes[k] = new VegType(newData[j], newData[j+1], Integer.parseInt(newData[j+2]), Double.parseDouble(newData[j+3]));
                }
                Vegs[i]=new Veg(newData[0], newData[1], newData[2], VegTypes, newData[newData.length-1]);
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I follow your answer, how should I insert the VegTypes array object into the  `Vegs[i] = new Veg(newData[0], newData[1], newData[2],);` if I have more than one VegType array object for each vegetable?

Comment: can you provide the `class Veg` as well?

Comment: @WetzelSchultz I updated the answer, please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
                //For loop to store information into VegTypes
                for (int f = 0; j < vegQuantity; f++) {
                    
                    VegTypes[f] = new VegType();
                    
                }
```

you need to use f to adjust the index into your array of fields.

```
                for (int f = 0; j < vegQuantity; f++) {
                    String vegCode = newLine[f*4 + 4];
                    String vegBatch = newLine[f*4 + 5];
                    int vegQuantity = Integer.parse(newLine[f*4 + 6]);
                    double vegGrade = Double.parse(newLine[f*4 + 7]);

                    VegTypes[f] = new VegType(vegCode, vegBatch, vegQuantity, vegGrade);
                    
                }
```